# What is the sense of Query in AWS DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In AWS DynamoDB you must specify a `partition key, which make it just work like GetItem ... because partition key is unique so it is supposed to return only one item, so if I know the ID of that item, it make no sense anymore to query! because query meant to be for constrains ...

so can someone give me example where querying one partition key can return multiple items ?

```
# Create single-attribute primary key table
aws dynamodb create-table --table-name testdb6 --attribute-definitions '[{"AttributeName": "Id", "AttributeType": "S"}]' --key-schema '[{"AttributeName": "Id", "KeyType": "HASH"}]' --provisioned-throughput '{"ReadCapacityUnits": 5, "WriteCapacityUnits": 5}' 

# Populate table
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name testdb6 --item '{ "Id": {"S": "1"}, "LastName": {"S": "Lopez"}, "FirstName": {"S": "Maria"}}'
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name testdb6 --item '{ "Id": {"S": "2"}, "LastName": {"S": "Fernandez"}, "FirstName": {"S": "Augusto"}}'

# Query table using only partition attribute
aws dynamodb query --table-name testdb6 --select ALL_ATTRIBUTES --key-conditions '{"Id": {"AttributeValueList": [{"S": "1"}], "ComparisonOperator": "EQ"}}'
```

You also can only use the `EQ` Operator for `partition key`, so using for example `BETWEEN` or `OR` or `IN` is not allowed on `partition key`

alternative to `query` there is `scan` but

- scan is expensive (slow)
- you can't sort on scan

## Update

so I realized I can use sort key, and then in this case `partition key` can be my table name, so I need to change my vocabularies

- **Table** -> Database
- **Partition Key** -> Table / Collection
- **Sort Key** -> Primary Key / ObjectId

**Example :** table **my-api** with `partition key -> className` and `sort key -> id`

```
my-api
   className | id | username | title
   _User     |  0 | "bingo"  |
   _User     |  1 | "mimi"   |
   _Song     |  0 |          | "You with me"
```

it is weird design

Comment: query is used to filter by columns other that partition key, for example by sort key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the table has **both partition key and sort key** and **query by partition key** alone will give you multiple items.

- Partition key - must for using Query API
- Sort key - optional while using Query API

**Get API:-**

> For a composite primary key, you must provide values for both the
>   partition key and the sort key.

So, Get API will always return only one item. Also, there is no filter expression to filter by non-key attributes.

Comment: Filter by non -key attribute - You can create 'global secondary index'  using the non - key attribute as the partition key. There is a limit of 5 gsi per table.

Answer (score 0):

Querying is for finding Items based on Primary or Index Key attributes. Primary Key can have one Partition Key (hash key) and one optional Range Key. If Range key present, then you can have multiple records with same Partition Key. So to perform `GetItem` operation on this kind of composite primary key you need to specify Range Key with Hash key.

Also, You can specify multiple Global Secondary Indexes (GSI) and Local Secondary Indexes (LSI), through which you can query non-key attributes.

So, Query operation provides you means to find items based on either Primary key, LSI or GSI's hash key and Range key's attributes.

Now, the example you used, is certainly not a good approach to design your schema.

---

**Table != Database**

Table == Table and DynamoDB houses all the tables.

`User`, `Song` etc needs to be stored in different tables. Then you can specify `id`, `username` to further uniquely identify items of your table. Each item can be thought of as record in RDBMS. Read more about choosing primary key and indexes and all information from [AWS DynamoDB Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html)

Comment: tell me how to query a user with its email without knowing its id or username supposing you have a Table User with `id` as partition key and `username` as sort/range key, and every id will be associated with 1 user only?

Comment: Yes, every id will be associated with a user. Or, if your each user will always have unique `username` then you can specify `username` as partition key. But that's your preference, and for querying through email, you can specify `email` as Hash key of Global Secondary Index, which will allow you to query users via `email`.

Answer (score 0):

Partition key would always return unique result if there is no sort key defined.
Configuring sort key to your table means that the combination between partition key and sort key must be unique.
For best practise defining the structure of your table please refer to [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/)